# Argument specified multiple times in boost program options

Tags: c++, boost, command-line-arguments

I would just like to allow my user to specify the verbosity level by using multiple times the flag `-v` or `--verbose`. For instance:

- `foobar -v` : verbosity level is 1
- `foobar` : verbosity level is 0
- `foobar -vvv` : verbosity level is 3

My current setting is:

```
po::options_description desc("Options for this program");
desc.add_options()
    ("verbose,v", "Turn on verbose mode")
    ...
;

po::variables_map opts;
po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), opts);
po::notify(opts);

const int verbosity = opts.count("verbose"); // Can be 0 or 1
```

How should I modify this code so to allow verbosity to be greater than 1?

(Of course I could allow an option like `-v 2`, but I prefer `-vv` in this case, which is quite common.)

Comment: In the duplicate, the last part of the answer contains an example that should do what you want.